# Conver string to date fails without error message on power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a power BI table (date_table_2)  with a Date column with is detected as text, this is the format of the values when I plot then on a table:

[image]

```
fecha_2 = DATE(LEFT(date_table_2[FECHA];4);MID(date_table_2[FECHA];5;2);RIGHT(date_table_2[FECHA];2))
```

This does not generates errors on the editor and the new column seems to be fine

[image]

But when I try to plot it every wiget where I tried it breaks. E.G. this with the splitter :

[image]

Comment: For month you are fetching the minus sign and the first digit. Your start position is incorrect. It should be 6 instead of 5. `MID(date_table_2[FECHA];5;2)` should become `MID(date_table_2[FECHA];6;2)`.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Yes it seems it was that.